# Syntax error when importing pykml.factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pykml

So I am trying to use pyKML to create a KML file for google earth however when I try and import the module, I get the following:

```
 from pykml.factory import KML_ElementMaker as KML
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-69-cdeb04502fb8>", line 1, in <module>
    from pykml.factory import KML_ElementMaker as KML

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pykml\factory.py", line 216
    print write_python_script_for_kml_document(doc)
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to use simpleKML but it is not available for python 3.6

Comment: Looks like you can only use `python2` :(

Comment: What makes you think *this* module is available for Python 3.6?

Comment: `simplekml` didn't work for you?  I had same error with `pyKML`, but [`simplekml`](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#getting-started) worked great for me!

Comment: @BruceWayne I ended up using simplekml with an older version of python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print write_python_script_for_kml_document(doc)
```

is a line of code which works in Python 2, but doesn't in Python 3. As Python 3 requires parentheses:

```
print(write_python_script_for_kml_document(doc))
```

So I guess the library you are trying to use hasn't been adapted to Python 3. Or at least this version hasn't.

Comment: Shoot you're right, don't know why anaconda let me install it and all then when it wouldn't let me install simpleKML because it wasn't compatible. Maybe I will just have to revert to a former version of python. Oh well. No big loss.

Comment: Not sure how it works on Windows, but usually you are able to have multiple versions of Python installed on a single machine - incl. a Python 2 and a Python 3 one.

Comment: I'm certain I can have multiple versions of python installed, my only issue is how I would install the simpleKML or pyKML packages through the anaconda prompt with multiple instances of python installed. Guess that's my next mission! Thanks for the help.